# nHibernate session and multithreading

Tags: c#, multithreading, nhibernate, session

I had a method with a lot of persistence calls that used a nHibernate session, it worked, was alright. But I needed to refactor this method, extracting a method from a content inside a loop, for multithread reasons. Then I created an class with this method. It is like a normal refactoring, but the nHibernate session inside this method call is broken, without context, I didn't finalize it at any moment. **Has nHibernate problems with multithreading?** Even when I have only one more thread executing, I have the same problem.

I use nHibernate Session through a SessionFactory and Façade pattern, it means, the session is not a field of these objects, it is global at SessionFactory.

---

Making it a little bit more clear:

**BEFORE:**

```
Method()
{
... persistence calls
foreach(Thing..)
{
...persistence calls for each thing (1)
}
...
}
```

**AFTER:**

```
Method()
{
... persistence calls
foreach(Thing..)
{
create a thingResolver object with some data
open a new thread with thingResolver.Method (1)
starts this thread
}
.. waits for finishing threads and continues
}
```

---

Our nHibernate Session Factory is thread-aware, and stores/retrieves nHibernate session per thread. It is working nicely now ;)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Sessions are **not thread safe** in NHibernate **by design**.
So it should be ok as long as you have a *session used by only one thread*.

I'm not sure what you're thingResolver does, but if it does some persistance calls on *the same* session you've created in the originating thread - this most probably the cause of your problems, you could create a separate session in your new thread so that it would be a session per thread if my assumption is true.

NHibernate reference has it in section 10.2

http://nhibernate.info/doc/nh/en/index.html#transactions

Comment: thanks Aleksey. I will have problems to do it (work with another session), since it violates my design, I'm thinking about forgeting this multithread thing.

Comment: in fact, my session factory is robust and can mantain a session per thread, its working :D

Comment: Updated link to documentation
http://nhforge.org/doc/nh/en/index.html#transactions

Comment: Just a small note for next generations: some libraries are not singlethread, even if you think they are. We used a custom **log4net** `Appender` with NHibernate `Session` instance and then we spent almost a month looking for a bug caused by the simple fact that log4net writes logs in another thread.

Answer (score 0):

You can have one NHibernate SessionFactory for multiple threads as long as you have a separate NHibernate session for each thread.

here is an example that will give exceptions because it uses the same session for each thread:

https://forum.hibernate.org/viewtopic.php?p=2373236&sid=db537baa5a57e3968abdda5cceec2a24

The solution is to store sessions on the LocaldataStoreSlot, that way you can have a session-per-request model.