# NHibernate Throwing erros in MultiThreading Scenarios

Tags: nhibernate

I am having problems when my Nhibernate code is load tested. I am using Nhibernate 3.1 version and the Nhibernate usage is exposed though a WCF service. It works properly in a single thread scenario and when it is subject to load test it crashes throwing multiple errors. 
Following are some of the error thrown during the load test.

1) `NHibernate.DuplicateMappingException: Duplicate class/entity mapping`
2) `System.ObjectDisposedException: Session is closed!
Object name: 'ISession'.   at NHibernate.Impl.AbstractSessionImpl.ErrorIfClosed()
   at NHibernate.Impl.AbstractSessionImpl.CheckAndUpdateSessionStatus()
   at NHibernate.Impl.SessionImpl.get_Batcher()`
Is it because I am spanning single session across multiple threads?

I used Contextual sessions and that did not help much too.

Can anyone help me finding the solution for this?

Comment: Yes, don't use sessions across threads. Turns out to be a possible duplicate of [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/242961/nhibernate-session-and-multithreading).

Comment: Since you're using WCF, you should create a Session Per Request, if your request has many threads... :S then create a Session Per Thread.

Answer (score 0):

You should be creating one session per thread. Each time you spawn a thread, create a session for it, and keep it open for the duration of the thread.

Comment: What is the best way to create a session per thread? Is it ok if we use the service Behaviour Attribute '[ServiceBehavior(InstanceContextMode = InstanceContextMode.PerCall)]' or make any other changes in the Nhibernate code?