# NHibernate repository for SQLite sometimes saves entity to wrong table

Tags: c#, nhibernate, sqlite

I have this repository:

```
 public class RepositorySQLite : IRepository
    {
        public void Add<T>(T entity)
        {
            using (ISession session = SessionProviderSqLite.OpenSession())
            using (ITransaction transaction = session.BeginTransaction())
            {
                session.Save(entity);
                transaction.Commit();
            }
        }

      ...
     }
```

I am using it like this:

```
public class Entity1: IEntity
{
        public virtual long SomeProperty { get; set; }
}

public class Entity2: IEntity
{
        public virtual long AnotherProperty { get; set; }
}

 IEntity entity = new Entity1();
 entity.SomeProperty = 123;


 IRepository repository = new RepositorySQLite();
             repository.Add(entity);
```

Entity mapping:

Each entity has own table called Entity1, Entity2, ...
All is ok, but sometimes Entity1 is stored in Entity2 table.
My code is running on more then one thread. I am using Lock statement. Nhibernate is configured by XML. I am using NUnit test for all repository methods.
This happend in my app for the first time after one year of normal work.

Possible solutions:
- should I use session.Save(string entityName, object entity)? But how? How can I get entityName?

Comment: How are your mappings defined? How is `IEntity` defined?

Answer (score 1):

I think your problem lies with this sentence `My code is running on more then one thread`. I would revisit this as sessions are `not` thread safe. Also see this [S.O. post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/242961/nhibernate-session-and-multithreading) for more info.

The golden rule is:- `Make sure that you are not using the same session between different threads`.

Answer (score 0):

This definitely sounds like a bug in your code. Probably, there is some `repository.Add(entity)` where `entity` is a reference to the unexpected "EntityX".

To make use of the `session.Save(string entityName, object entity)` overload, try the code below:

```
    public void Add<T>(T entity)
    {
        using (ISession session = SessionProviderSqLite.OpenSession())
        using (ITransaction transaction = session.BeginTransaction())
        {
            session.Save(typeof(T).FullName, entity)
            transaction.Commit();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Also, please make sure you are following Rippo's advice: Make sure that you are not using the same session between different threads.